# React / Redux Authentication Route not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux

** Note this is in a react class component

```
DefaultContainer = () => {
    return (
      <div className="app_container">
        <SideNav />
        <TopBar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/recent" component={Recent} />
        <Route path="/AddNote" component={AddNote} />
        <Route path="/ToDo" component={ToDo} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  // Check for authenticaition

  AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
          if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {            
             return <Component {...props} />;
          }
          else {
            return (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/login",
                  state: { from: props.location }
                }}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={this.LogInContainer} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={this.RegisterContainer} />
          <this.AuthRoute  component={this.DefaultContainer} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

I login, this.props.isAuthenticated is set to true. When I try to visit the '/' route I get redirected back to the login? But this.props.isAuthenticated is true in React Dev tools? Cannot grasp what is going wrong.

Comment: AuthRoute does not look like a class and therefore does not have a `this`.

Comment: @colburton its a react component

Comment: If you do `AuthRoute extends React.Component ...` you have a this.props. If you do `AuthRoute = (props) => ...` you get the props injected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as simple as this:

```
AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
          if (props.isAuthenticated) {            // <- here is the difference
             return <Component {...props} />;
          }
          else {
            return (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/login",
                  state: { from: props.location }
                }}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  };
```